# Python UDP networking socket.error: [Errno 10049]

Tags: python-2.7, networking, udp

I am trying to establish a simple UDP connection using Python code, between 2 PCs through internet. 
Code run on PC_1:

```
import socket
import time

HOST = "ip_address_of_PC2"
PORT = 5555
data = "Hello World!!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    s.sendto(data, (HOST, PORT))
    print "sent: ",data
    time.sleep(1)
```

code run on the 2nd PC:

```
import socket

HOST = "ip_address_of_PC1"
PORT = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    print s.recv(30)
```

While running the code on 2nd PC am getting following error message:

```
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `print s.recv(30)` to:

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(30)
print data
```

and in the 2nd PC code, the HOST variable needs the value of the 2nd PC ip, not the first one:

```
HOST = "ip_address_of_PC2"
```

Comment: it worked when changed HOST variable of PC2 to private ipv4 address of PC2 and HOST variable of PC1 to public ipv4 address of PC2.

Answer (score 0):

Code run on PC1:

```
import socket
import time

HOST = "public ip_address_of_PC2"
PORT = 5555
data = "Hello World!!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    s.sendto(data, (HOST, PORT))
    print "sent: ",data
    time.sleep(1)
```

Code run on PC2:

```
import socket

HOST = "private ip_address_of_PC2"
PORT = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    print s.recv(30)
```